# Angular Material 2 DatePicker Date Format Using Moment

Tags: angular, momentjs, angular-material2

I am using Angular Material 2 date picker and want to format the date like - 'Sat 02-Mar-19'.

There is a [guideline](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples) how to do that in Angular Material, as I am new to moment js and not familiar with it, so not able to get the expected format.

I tried to format the date by looking into the moment doc by changing the options provided by Angular Material but no luck.

What change I should do into the configuration provided by Angular material to get the date like - 'Sat 02-Mar-19'.

Comment: actually with material you can use "native" picker or "moment" picker. I found "moment" to be better cross-platforms

Comment: Any demo/plunker please ?

Answer (score 2):

After spending a few hours on moment js document following material [config](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples) work perfectly -

```
export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'ddd DD-MMM-YY',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'ddd DD-MMM-YY'
  }
};
```

Hoping that this will save an hour for someone.